# Multiple key names, same pair value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to setup an object literal in a JavaScript script that has a key with multiple names. referring to the same object value i.e. something like these that I have already tried:

```
var holidays: {
    "thanksgiving day", "thanksgiving", "t-day": {
        someValue : "foo"
    }
}

var holidays: {
    ["thanksgiving day", "thanksgiving", "t-day"]: {
        someValue : "foo"
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Another approach is to do some postprocessing

```
function expand(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
        var key = keys[i],
            subkeys = key.split(/,\s?/),
            target = obj[key];
        delete obj[key];
        subkeys.forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = target; })
    }
    return obj;
}

var holidays = expand({
    "thanksgiving day, thanksgiving, t-day": {
        someValue : "foo"
    } 
});
```

Comment: This is better than my suggestion.  So long as your data doesn't include commas, I would go with this answer.

Comment: Why the mix of a `for` loop and a `forEach`?  I would find it cleaner to stick with one style, probably `forEach`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, you're right. Firstly I used `for` because I knew that its body will be not so small, while when I iterate over subkeys I execute only one statement, so I was too lazy to write `for (var blah...`. But there is no reason to mix both styles, sure.

Comment: This should do it. I had to prototype in Object.keys and forEach though. Using it in a JScript MS Runtime rather than in a browser. This code is really good. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 22):

JSON does not offer such a feature, nor do Javascript object literals.

You might be able to make do with something like this:

```
holidays = {
    thanksgiving: {foo: 'foo'},
    groundhogDay: {foo: 'bar'},
    aliases: {
        'thanksgiving day': 'thanksgiving',
        't-day': 'thanksgiving',
        'Bill Murrays nightmare': 'groundhogDay'
    }
}
```

and then you can check

```
holidays[name] || holidays[holidays.aliases[name]]
```

for your data.

It's not a wonderful solution.  But it wouldn't be too difficult to write a little function that created this sort of object out of a representation like:

```
[
    {
        names: ['thanksgiving', 'thanksgiving day', 't-day'],
        obj: {foo: 'foo'}
    },
    {
        names: ['groundhogDay', 'Bill Murrays nightmare'],
        obj: {foo: 'bar'}
    },
]
```

if that would be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution, if you can afford RegExp execution, and ES6 Proxy:

```
let align = new Proxy({
    
    'start|top|left': -1,
    'middle|center': 0,
    'end|bottom|right': 1,

}, {

    get: function(target, property, receiver) {

        for (let k in target)
            if (new RegExp(k).test(property))
                return target[k]

        return null

    }

})

align.start     // -1
align.top       // -1
align.left      // -1

align.middle    // 0
align.center    // 0

align.end       // 1
align.bottom    // 1
align.right     // 1
```

See [MDN Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get)

2021 EDIT:
Another (cleaner?) solution using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) & [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) :

```
const myDict = [
    // list of pairs [value, keys],
    // note that a key should appear only once
    [-1, ['start', 'left', 'top']],
    [0, ['center', 'middle']],
    [1, ['end', 'right', 'bottom']],
].reduce((obj, [value, keys]) => {
    for (const key of keys) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { value })
    }
    return obj
}, {})
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get

Comment: Why return `null`, though? Shouldn't that just be `undefined`, as usual?

Comment: Wow, not so old, but i totally forget that piece of code. Returning null is a convenient way to say "hey, i understand your query, but there is nothing for you here". Since a Proxy is used here, and knowing that a Proxy can handle any "get" access, i found relevant to return null. But returning undefined is correct too, of course.

Comment: Sorry, but if you ask me, that could only prohibit people from explicitly using `null` on their own terms.

Comment: I don't see the point of adding `reciever` when you don't use it. I omitted it and it worked fine. (Also, don't need `null` if you know *for sure* that the key will be there).

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
var holidays = {
  'thanksgiving day': {
    foo: 'foo'
  }
};

holidays.thanksgiving = holidays['t-day'] = holidays['thanksgiving day'];
```

If you see yourself doing this often or you have more values consider this pattern:

```
'thanksgiving, t-day, thanks, thank, thank u'.split(',').forEach(function(key) {
  holidays[key] = holidays['thanksgiving day'];
});
```

A better approach would be to process your data beforehand instead of adding duplicates.

Comment: In case anyone is curious about how this works: In JavaScript, objects are stored by references (whereas literal numbers and strings, which can only be copied). Here, by storing a *reference* to an object that contains the value, when you change the value in any way, all the other properties can access the new value using the same reference.

Answer (score 3):

With ES6 you could do it like this, but it's not ideal:

```
const holidays = {
    "single": {
        singleValue: "foo",
    },

    ...([
        "thanksgiving day", "thanksgiving", "t-day",
    ].reduce((a, v) => ({...a, [v]: {
        someValue: "foo",
    }}), {})),

    "other": {
        otherValue: "foo",
    },
};
```

I still think the cleanest solution is probably:

```
let holidays = {
    "t-day": {
        someValue: "foo",
    },
};
holidays["thanksgiving"] = holidays["t-day"];
holidays["thanksgiving day"] = holidays["t-day"];
```

Answer (score 2):

That should work as expected:

```
function getItem(_key) {
    items = [{
        item: 'a',
        keys: ['xyz','foo']
    },{
        item: 'b',
        keys: ['xwt','bar']
    }];

    _filtered = items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.keys.indexOf(_key) != -1
    }).map(function(item) {
        return item.item;
    });
    return !!_filtered.length ? _filtered[0] : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now this may be overkill for you, but here's a generic function that will create an object with "multiple keys." What it actually does is have one real property with the actual value, and then defines getters and setters to forward operations from the virtual keys to the actual property.

```
function multiKey(keyGroups) {
    let obj = {};
    let props = {};

    for (let keyGroup of keyGroups) {
        let masterKey = keyGroup[0];
        let prop = {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: false,

            get() {
                return obj[masterKey];
            },

            set(value) {
                obj[masterKey] = value;
            }
        };

        obj[masterKey] = undefined;
        for (let i = 1; i < keyGroup.length; ++i) {
            if (keyGroup.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                props[keyGroup[i]] = prop;
            }
        }
    }

    return Object.defineProperties(obj, props);
}
```

This is less sketchy than you would expect, has basically no performance penalty once the object is created, and behaves nicely with enumeration (`for...in` loops) and membership testing (`in` operator). Here's some example usage:

```
let test = multiKey([
    ['north', 'up'],
    ['south', 'down'],
    ['east', 'left'],
    ['west', 'right']
]);

test.north = 42;
test.down = 123;

test.up; // returns 42
test.south; // returns 123

let count = 0;
for (let key in test) {
    count += 1;
}

count === 4; // true; only unique (un-linked) properties are looped over
```

Taken from [my Gist](https://gist.github.com/rvighne/d31c57dd63a0bf1253f571389608db5a), which you may fork.

Answer (score 1):

Same reponse (ES6 Proxy, RegExp), but in a shorter way (and significantly less legible)

```
let align = new Proxy({

    'start|top|left': -1,
    'middle|center': 0,
    'end|bottom|right': 1,

}, { get: (t, p) => Object.keys(t).reduce((r, v) => r !== undefined ? r : (new RegExp(v).test(p) ? t[v] : undefined), undefined) })

align.start     // -1
align.top       // -1
align.left      // -1

align.middle    // 0
align.center    // 0

align.end       // 1
align.bottom    // 1
align.right     // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//create some objects(!) you want to have aliases for..like tags
var {learn,image,programming} = 
 ["learn", "image", "programming"].map(tag=>({toString:()=>tag }));


//create arbitrary many aliases using a Map
var alias = new Map();
alias.set("photo", image);
alias.set("pic", image);
alias.set("learning", learn);
alias.set("coding", programming);

//best put the original tagNames in here too.. 
//pretty easy huh? 

// returns the image object 
alias.get("pic");

// ;)
```

Comment: please explain your code, also. Only posting code won't help OP.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way you can initialize an object with several keys sharing the same value

```
var holidays = {
    ...["thanksgiving day", "thanksgiving", "t-day"].reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: 'foo' }), {})
}
```

although I would personally think it was more clear if it was written out

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) produces some fairly readable and concise code:

```javascript
var holidays = Object.fromEntries(
        ["thanksgiving day", "thanksgiving", "t-day"].map(k => [k, "foo"]));
```

The spread syntax can be used to include this alongside other key/value pairs:

```javascript
var holidaysAndMore = {
    "A": "a",
    ...Object.fromEntries(
            ["thanksgiving day", "thanksgiving", "t-day"].map(k => [k, "foo"])),
    "B": "b"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with different keys pointing to the same object and a  [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for shaping setting and getting.

The advantage is to use multiple entry pairs with an array of keys and a value and having only a single value for all grouped keys.

```js
const
    etepetete = entries => new Proxy(
        Object.fromEntries(entries.flatMap(([keys, value]) => keys.map((v => k => [k, v])({ value })))),
        {
            get (target, prop, receiver) {
                if (prop in target) return target[prop].value;
                return Reflect.get(...arguments);
            },
            set (target, prop, value, receiver) {
                if (prop in target) {
                    target[prop].value = value;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    ),
    holiday = etepetete([
        [["thanksgiving day", "thanksgiving", "t-day"], "foo"]
    ]);

console.log(holiday['t-day']);
holiday['thanksgiving day'] = 'bar';
console.log(holiday['t-day']);
```