# How to have two class names share the same style in ReactJS useStyles

Tags: reactjs

ReactJS useStyles newbie question. In regular CSS I can have two classes share the same style, such as...

`.firstDiv, .secondDiv { border: 1px solid red; }`

but I'm not clear on how I would do this using ReactJS useStyle.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    firstDiv: {
       border: "border: 1px solid red"
    },
    secondDiv: {
       border: "border: 1px solid red"
    }
})
```

I tried   `firstDiv, secondDiv: { border: "border: 1px solid red" }` but doing so just returns a reference error stating firstDiv isn't defined.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I'm sure it's a simple syntax issue but all of my searching online only returns examples on how to add two classes to an element, which isn't what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you just make one class? Do some of them have other rules, not applicable to another one?

Comment: @Cerberus The example provided is simplified. I need to hide the border on firstDiv when hovering over secondDiv. Similar to example seen at https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-div-jss-cjdn8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `makeStyles` takes a JavaScript function that returns an object, your question really is: "How to create an object, where two object keys have the same value?"

For that question, you may found the answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743536/multiple-key-names-same-pair-value).

If you want that for instance that two classes share some properties, that is only possible if you extract them:

```
const sharedProperties = {
   border: "border: 1px solid red",
   color: "red"
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    firstDiv: {
       fontSize: 10,
       ...sharedProperties, 
    },
    secondDiv: {
       fontSize: 20,
       ...sharedProperties,
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Laczkó Örs! Your example works as intended. I wish there were a cleaner way of doing this all within useStyles to avoid having to create another const but it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Really happy to help!